# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, corruption

```
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-09 10:21:44 1624 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 19862295 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-09-09 10:21:44 5776 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace casualme/scraped_user uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\casualme\scraped_user.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

My phpmyadmin is not working. How can I make it work again? I have a very large database.

I have the following files. `db.opt` , `scraped_user.frm` , `scraped_user.ibd` is there a way to recover my database from these files? I just want to get the table's data.

I want to reinstall my xampp but is there a way to back up my db when I can't run it? Like copying this folder 'DBNAME' with files `db.opt`, `scraped_user.frm`, `scraped_user.ibd`.

I tried the first option suggested by InnoDB above. Still not working. In second I cant remove the `.ibd` file. I don't have a backup of my table. On the third item, I don't know where it is located. Been looking for it.

Comment: you can find your answer [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly/61859561#61859561)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to recover my data. (so happy)

After hours of reading forums and solutions I found a way to fix it. Here's what I did:

- In xampp I backed up my old copy (after crash) of folder `DbScrapes` (dbname) from `C:\xampp\mysql\data` with files `db.opt`, `scraped_user.frm`, `scraped_user.ibd`
- In `C:\xampp\mysql\data` I backed up an old copy (after crash) of files `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, `ibdata1`.
- Uninstalled my xampp
- Restarted my computer to be sure ports that xampp is using will be close
- Checked if there is a MySQL service in `services.msc`
- On my computer there was a MySQL service.
- I deleted it using cmd command `sc delete "service_name"`
- Restart again to make sure everything is fresh.
- Installed a new copy of xampp
- Test if apache and MySQL is ok, if it's ok click stop
- Copy the files that I have backed up to the location where I get them so it's `C:\xampp\mysql\data`
- Run xampp's apache and MySQL again.

Now I'm running xampp and I have my data.

**Note:** Don't delete `ibdata1` - it will delete all your database tables.

The crashing issue I think was a bug in xampp.

Answer (score -4):

Just add row `innodb_force_recovery = 1` in `my.ini` file.

Comment: Some explanation and maybe a link to more information should typically be added.